# How to display correctly a text field in MVC View?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning .NET MVC and I have a little problem with the text display.
I'm developing a little application's login and when I'm displaying User's name, it looks really bad(text has a bad style).
Is there a way to fix it?

Here's how it looks:

[image]

I want to fix it's style to look like the *Sign Out* or better somehow.

Here's the code in the my View:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    @if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account")</li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li>@(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name : "")</li>
                        <li> <a href="@Url.Action("SignOut","Account")">Sign out</a></li>
                    }
                </ul>
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is actually more likely a css issue. you can add an id or class attribute to the  link tag <a id='signout'...  then edit the .css file to have a section called #signout {} and put the styles you want in the curly braces. look up w3cschools css should help

Comment: Hello, I want to edit only Identity.Name's text style, only for this element. Is that possible by changing css parameters?

Comment: Yes, but if you want it to only work for this text, you need to identify it with an ID if it is something you want multiple elements to have you would need to do so with a class.

Comment: Thank you! Just figured it out and trying to find the nedded parameters.

Comment: try w3c schools they are a good resource

Comment: Yeah, I know they have good materials there. Thank you for your help!